# Can we use arduino libraries(e.g motor shield library) with the STM32?

Tags: arduino, stm32

I want to know if it is possible to use arduino libraries (e.g motor shield library) with the STM32 series? Has anybody tried it before?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Generally yes, *but*.

Arduino the software defines just an API. As long as your board has an implementation of that API, a library basing on it *should* work.

That being said, libraries that weren't tested specifically on STM32 might break for various reasons. If you use PlatformIO, you can look for libraries that use Arduino framework and support STM32 MCUs.

If you're using an Arduino IDE, it's also possible to program the STM controllers directly from it. You just need an appropriate core/board definition installed, and make sure that you pick an appropriate programming option (I personally use ST-link whenever I can instead of bootloaders+serial).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. So this means that I can program ANY STM32 µC with these libraries but I have to expect some complications with some of  the libraries? Did I understand that correctly? Or are there only some STM32 µC that support arduino libraries?

Comment: Specifically the ST-Nucleo L432KC because I could not find anything helpful regarding this question.

Comment: @Don_Corleone That one has is supported by [this core](https://github.com/stm32duino/Arduino_Core_STM32). You can simply try building your code on it and seeing what happens. Issues I've ran into in the past included mismatched pins, misconfigured SPI and stuff like that - but it might just work.

Comment: Thank you very much.